# adding CSS keyframe animation changes the image size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image inside a container and I've positioned it so that it fits exactly inside the container, but when I add the animation the image gets bigger and doesn't fit inside anymore.

Why this happens and how to fix the issue? (I haven't changed the sizes in the animation keyframes!)

```js
let correctImage = document.getElementById("correctImage");

//Add Animations
setTimeout(function(){
   correctImage.classList.add("roll-in-blurred-left");
}, 2000)
```

```css
.containerCorrectImage{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1vw;
  top: 3vh;
  height: 92vh;
  width: 18vw;   
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

#correctImage{
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); 
  width: 32vw;
  height:70vh;
  opacity:1;
  top: -16vh;
  left:-7vw;

}

/*
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation roll-in-blurred-left
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
 
.roll-in-blurred-left {
 -webkit-animation: roll-in-blurred-left 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
         animation: roll-in-blurred-left 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
            transform: translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
            filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes roll-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
            transform: translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
            filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerCorrectImage">
<img id="correctImage" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Study.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Sara, can you please add css-animations tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are animating the transform - which you already have scale on for your image.  You also need to add that scale to your animation:

```css
@keyframes roll-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
    filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Updated snippet:

```js
let correctImage = document.getElementById("correctImage");

//Add Animations
setTimeout(function() {
  correctImage.classList.add("roll-in-blurred-left");
}, 2000)
```

```css
.containerCorrectImage {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1vw;
  top: 3vh;
  height: 92vh;
  width: 18vw;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

#correctImage {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  width: 32vw;
  height: 70vh;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -16vh;
  left: -7vw;
}


/*
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation roll-in-blurred-left
 * ----------------------------------------
 */

.roll-in-blurred-left {
  -webkit-animation: roll-in-blurred-left 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
  animation: roll-in-blurred-left 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px) opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes roll-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg);
    filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerCorrectImage">
  <img id="correctImage" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Study.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

At present at `0%` in your `@keyframes`, you have:

```
transform: translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg)
```

You *also* need to include `scale(0.5, 0.5)` in the same `transform` value (and in its counterpart value in the `transform` at the end of the  `@keyframes`).

```js
let correctImage = document.getElementById("correctImage");

//Add Animations
setTimeout(function(){
   correctImage.classList.add("roll-in-blurred-left");
}, 2000)
```

```css
.containerCorrectImage{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 1vw;
  top: 3vh;
  height: 92vh;
  width: 18vw;   
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

#correctImage {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); 
  width: 32vw;
  height:70vh;
  opacity:1;
  top: -16vh;
  left:-7vw;

}

/*
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation roll-in-blurred-left
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
 
.roll-in-blurred-left {
  animation: roll-in-blurred-left 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000) both;
}

@keyframes roll-in-blurred-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-1000px) rotate(-720deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerCorrectImage">
<img id="correctImage" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Study.png"/>
</div>
```